# Increase speed of bind_rows within loop (3000 dataframes)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have parsed a very large database with over 5 Millions of data lines with 40 columns.
The results are split into small '.Rdata' files for practical reasons.
In total I have over 3000 files each being up to 1Mb of size.

I have designed a quick loop to combine these files into one sigle dataframe using dplyr, however this is very slow and I believe there are faster ways for this.

I tried to use matrices with preallocation but my data is both text and numbers and was getting errors.
Dataframes are even slower when using base R.

```
list_files = as.data.frame(list.files(path = "output", pattern = 'Rdata'))
names(list_files) = 'full_name'

list_files = list_files %>% 
    separate(full_name, sep ="_", into = c('col1','col2')) %>% 
        separate(col2, sep = '.R', into = c('col3','col4')) %>%
            mutate(col3 = as.numeric(col3)) %>% 
            arrange(col3) %>%  mutate(col3 = as.character(col3))

datax <- c()

for(i in 1:length(list_files$col3))
    {
        load(paste('output/MyData_',list_files$col3[i],'.Rdata',sep=''))
##here loads results_df2
        datax = datax %>% bind_rows(results_df2)
        if((i %% 100) == 0) { print(i)}
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this loop?

Comment: Excellent! Will post this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **dplyr** and **bind_rows**

```
system.time( for(i in 1:50) { datax = datax %>% bind_rows( ll[[i]]) })
```

results

```
user  system elapsed 
2.70    0.15    2.87
```

Using the **rbindlist** function

`system.time(ans1 <- rbindlist(ll))`

results

```
 user  system elapsed 
 0.05    0.00    0.04
```

This is exactly what I needed. Question is answered. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr::map` and `purrr::reduce`, you can import and bind them without using a for loop.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# save data frame as rds
# mtcars %>% saveRDS("mtcars1.rds")
# mtcars %>% saveRDS("mtcars2.rds")

# list files
files <- list.files(pattern = "rds")

# read and bind
files %>% map(readRDS) %>% 
                reduce(bind_rows)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but even map is a loop just written in rcpp or cpp or in a smarter way?
Anyway will test with benchmarking. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: I cannot apply this code to my Rdata files as when using the load() analogy I get the following error: ```Error: Argument 1 must have names```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

list_files = list.files(path = "output", pattern = 'Rdata')
lapply(list_files, function(x) load(x) %>% data.table() ) %>% rbindlist()
```

Comment: @Arkadiw Please post the results after you do

Comment: Your code takes forever to run while the bind_rows takes 7 seconds for 50 files.